# Finding duplicated names but different extension and moving to another folder on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to move some duplicated file names but different extension to another folder, imagine i have a folder with this files

file.txt

file.cmd

i want to detect that file.cmd file and move it to another folder

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [tour]. Please read [ask] a good question. Then provide a [mcve] of the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
.{
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
        $DestDirectoryName,

        [Parameter()]
        [stirng[]]
        $Include
    )

    $DestDirectoryName = Join-Path $DestDirectoryName -ChildPath "*"
    Get-ChildItem $DestDirectoryName -Include |
        Group-Object BaseName |
            Where-Object count -GT 1 | ForEach-Object {
                "{0}:" -f$_.Name
                $_.Group.foreach{
                    "`t {0}" -f $_.Name
                }
        
        }
} -DestDirectoryName "c:\tmp" -Include @('*.txt', '*.cmd')
```

Comment: Could you explain how this code checks to make sure the file extensions are `.CMD` and `.TXT`?

Comment: it didn’t happen, I forgot, I made changes

Comment: The user is requesting that if `file.txt` and `file.cmd` existing, then move `file.cmd` to a different folder.

Comment: user can use copy-item